High Memory Consumption Leads to System Freeze When Processing Video with OpenCV and GStreamer
I'm developing a video processing application using OpenCV and GStreamer on a Jetson Xavier NX. The application utilizes a YOLOv5s model for object detection. Despite successful video capture and processing, I encounter an issue where my system's memory (RAM and SWAP) gets completely filled up, leading to a system freeze.
Issue:
The application works fine initially but starts consuming increasing amounts of memory(RAM and SWP) with each processed frame. Eventually, it consumes all available memory, leading to a complete system freeze. I've confirmed this behavior through monitoring tools like htop.
What I've Tried:
Adjusted GStreamer pipeline settings to reduce the load.
Ensured that all resources were properly released, and used Python's garbage collection more aggressively.
Tested with simplified and more complex pipelines to ensure compatibility.
Used memory_profiler to identify potential leaks or inefficient memory usage (no specific leaks were apparent).
Current GStreamer Pipeline:
gst_pipeline = (
    'v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! '
    'video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! '
    'videoconvert ! '
    'videoscale ! '
    'video/x-raw, width=(int)600, height=(int)600 ! '
    'appsink'
)

Code Snippet:
import cv2
from yoloDet import YoloTRT

# Initializing the video capture with the GStreamer pipeline
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to grab frame")
        break
    # Processing frame with YOLO model
    detections, t = model.Inference(frame)
    # Displaying the frame
    cv2.imshow("Output", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

How can I manage or reduce memory usage to prevent the system from freezing? Are there any specific optimizations or adjustments in handling video streams or memory management in Python that I might have overlooked?
Additional Information:
Device: NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX(Jetpack 4.4) |
OpenCV version: 3.3.1 |
No errors are reported before the freeze, only increasing memory usage.
What I Am Looking For:
Suggestions on managing high memory usage in real-time video processing.
Any efficient practices for memory management in similar applications.
Insights into potential misconfigurations in GStreamer or OpenCV that could lead to such issues.

Your processing seems too slow. E.g. OpenCV does not pull samples fast enough from the pipeline. Byt default appsink has an unlimited buffer, potentially consuming all your memory.
Limit the number of buffers in your appsink via the max-buffer property. Also consider adding drop=true so data can be dropped from the appsink. Else data will be droppes upstream - in the camera which may report then errors by itself.
